# ng-model value as a minimum value in a time input

Tags: html, angularjs

It is possible using angularjs to put a ng-model value as a minimum value in a time-type input? I try this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="valueHour" name="valueHour" value="valueHour">
<input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
       placeholder="HH:mm:ss" min="valueHour" max="17:00:00" required />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you will need to interpolate the scope variable holding the desired minimum value:

```
<input type="time" 
       id="exampleInput" 
       name="input" 
       ng-model="example.value" 
       placeholder="HH:mm:ss" 
       min="{{valueHour}}" 
       max="17:00:00" 
       required />
```

As another answer mentioned, allowing free-text input may be dangerous as it will allow the user to type in invalid time values. You should consider making the input for the min value model a `time` input as well.